# Como adapto el siguiente codigo PHP de MySQL a SQL Server?

Tags: php, sql-server, mysqli

tengo un codigo en PHP y necesito la equivalencia de eso en SQL Server:

```
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_all($datos, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

LA VARIABLE $DATOS GUARDA EL SIGUIENTE CODIGO:

```
$datos = sqlsrv_query($conexion, "select codigo as id,
                                             titulo as title,
                                             descripcion,
                                             inicio as start,
                                             fin as end,
                                             colortexto as textColor,
                                             colorfondo as backgroundColor
                                         from eventos");
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Que tenes asignado en tu variable datos?

Comment: Nicolas tengo un sqlsrv_query

Comment: No existe equivalente directo a `mysqli_fetch_all()`. Te aconsejo que uses PDO para acceder a tu base de datos, así migrar el código de un SGBD a otro es más sencillo. Redacto una respuesta con una posible solución.

Answer (score 0):

No existe equivalencia directa de [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](https://php.net/es/mysqli_fetch_all) en las funciones `sqlsrv_*`, por lo que deberás hacer un bucle para obtener todos los resultados (usando, por ejemplo, [`sqlsrv_fetch_array()`](https://php.net/es/sqlsrv_fetch_array)) de la siguiente manera:

```
/* $resultado será inicialmente una matriz vacía */
$resultado = [];
/* Obtenemos cada fila en forma de matriz asociativa */
while ($fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($datos, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) !== NULL
  && $fila !== false
) {
  /* Agregamos al resultado cada una de las filas obtenidas */
  array_push($resultado, $fila);
}
/* En caso de error debemos gestionarlo */
if ($fila === false) {
  /* Gestionar el error */
  var_export(sqlsrv_errors());
  die();
}
```

Para terminar, te recomiendo migrar tu código a [PDO / SQL Server](https://php.net/es/ref.pdo-sqlsrv), ya que pasar de un SGBD a otro es mucho más sencillo.